# Как получить цвет пикселя Android Delphi 10.3?

Tags: android, delphi, изображения

Надо прочесть картинку с камеры мобильного. И проанализировать изображение. По результатам менять яркость, контрастность, переводить в Ч/белое. Ну и бегать по пикселям анализируя цвет.

Для десктоп приложений проблем нет. А вот с Android-ом впервые работаю.
Не нашел функций  подобных `Image1.Canvas.Pixels[i, j]`,
`GetRValue(c)` ...

Answer (score 0):

Используй Bitmap.Map(). Метод вернёт структуру для доступа к текстуре. Там есть прямой доступ к пикселям. Не забудь вызвать Bitmap.Unmap() по завершении работы.